# What account do COM+ components run under when regasm is used?

Tags: com+, regasm

What account do COM+ components run under when registered via the regasm tool?  I didn't notice any command parameters for regasm to identify the account. Given regasm requires admin privileges to run, I'm assuming COM+ components run w/admin privs as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What language is your component written in?
if it's in .NET you can set assembly attributes that can control the security configuration of your COM+ application.

checkout http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c11b9998.aspx

and in particular: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enterpriseservices.applicationaccesscontrolattribute.aspx

I don't know of any command parameters for regasm that can give you permissions.
if you will be more specific about what you are trying to do, I might be able to help you.